# How - can I always detect the last directory from complete directory path

Tags: shell

Need to print last directory from following example. Directory structures looks like below:

`"/home/user/example/bar" 
"/home/user/example/backup/foo"
"/home/user/example/bar1"
"/home/user/example/backup/tmp/bar2"
"/home/user/example/bar3"
"/home/user/example/bar4"`

ONLY IF my complete directory path contains "example" directory then I need the last directory (bar , foo, bar1, bar2, bar3, bar4) into some variable.
How can I always detect the last directory (bar , foo, bar1, bar2, bar3, bar4)  like the example above?

Also If my directory path contains **example** then I need to fetch the immediate directory after the example. 

    `"/home/user/example/backup/foo"      result should be backup
    "/home/user/example/bar1"  result should be bar1
    "/home/user/example/backup/tmp/bar2"  result should be backup
    "/home/user/example/bar3"   result should be bar3
    "/home/user/example/bar4"  result should be bar4`

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: check `basename` command.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
DIR="/home/user/example/bar3"
if [ "${DIR##*/example/*}" = "" ]; then
    echo "Contains example"
    LAST_DIR="${DIR##*/}"
    echo "Last dir is: ${LAST_DIR}"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks Andriy. It works well as needed. _italic_ How to change this to work for `code` "/home/user/example/backup/foo" ... Let's say I need to fetch only the directory **backup** from my path which contains a directory example. <b> Basically I need to get only the directory which comes after **example** from all the path I mentioned.